# Increasing maxRequestLength in ServiceStack for specific route

Tags: c#, web-config, servicestack

So I recently wrote a simple service to upload files to my server. Everything works fine. My web.config looks like this (max upload size is restricted to 20 MB):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" executionTimeout="600" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="api*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    ...
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

All my routes begin with /api/, for example my upload service is at /api/documents/upload.

Now my question is: Is it possible to define different upload sizes for different services? (in my example every service is limited to 20 MB!)

I tried some stuff with the location-tag but it didn't worked with the httpRuntime-tag. Anyone tried something like this already?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  element, it should work (Check the path without `~/`)

```
<configuration>
  <location path="api/documents/upload">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security> 
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ok I tried your solution, but I still need the tag httpHandlers like in my first post (for my other services). And I think it may hide the location path tag? Because I get an exception ("Upload size exceeds httpRuntime limit") when I try to upload any documents.

Comment: Did you ever find out how?